# Android Error:(3) No resource identifier found for attribute when swiched from static google package to dynamic compile on gradle

Tags: android

I am using google play services on my app for some years as static, now I switched on Gradle to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
```

and when I build I got:

```
Error:(19, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless').
Error:(50, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless').

Error:(3) No resource identifier found for attribute 'indeterminateTint' in package 'android'
Error:(3) No resource identifier found for attribute 'indeterminateTintMode' in package 'android'


Error:Execution failed for task ':Code:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\dev\tools\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

This files are automatically generating so edit them not helping..

Answer (score 0):

In the XML file changes

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

to

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```